# Scraping information from a webpage using Excel\VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from a webpage, I require 4 bits of data, 2 of which I've been able to retrieve but the other 2 allude me.

It's not a fixed URL, but this URL is already being retrieved from IE after a redirect, so for this example, I will use:
[https://cpc.farnell.com/warton/microprint-p2010-15-32um-250g/solder-paste-15-32um-250g-pot/dp/SD02808](https://stackoverflow.com)

I wish to obtain the title:

**Microprint P2010 No Clean, Lead Free Solder Paste, 15-32um, 250g Pot - MICROPRINT P2010 15-32UM, 250G**

and the Manufacturer Part Number

**MICROPRINT P2010 15-32UM, 250G**

I have been using **getElementbyID** for the Product Overview/Product Information, which has worked fine, but the other text fields don't appear to work (I looked at the Xpath and it errors on Object required in VBE)

I was successful for the 2 other elements using the below:

```
Sub Mani()

'Declare variables
Dim objWeb As Object
Dim objHTML As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim strData, StrData1 As String


Set objWeb = CreateObject("internetexplorer.Application")
str = "https://cpc.farnell.com/"

objWeb.navigate str & Cells(1, 1).Value


While objWeb.Busy = True
Wend

FullURL = objWeb.LocationURL

Range("b2").Value = FullURL

objWeb.navigate FullURL

'IE.Visible = True
   
While objWeb.Busy = True
Wend

Set objHTML = objWeb.document

strData = objHTML.getElementById("pdpSection_FAndB").innerText

ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Value = strData

strData = objHTML.getElementById("pdpSection_pdpProdDetails").innerText
Set strData = Nothing

ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value = strData
    
objWeb.Quit
   

End Sub
```

The URL reloading is to navigate around a URL redirect,

https://cpc.farnell.com/SD02808

redirects to the main url

https://cpc.farnell.com/warton/microprint-p2010-15-32um-250g/solder-paste-15-32um-250g-pot/dp/SD02808

I want to input the part number into A1, which Excel will use as a variable in VB, then reread the full url from the IE instance.
This is legacy from when trying to use **Get data from Web** which didn't work too well due to page script errors, hence using an IE instance.

Comment: People are much less likely to help you if you post a single line of non-working code: you're asking them to write the rest just to get to the point where they can test out different approaches.  If you post the full code it's a quick copy-paste.

Comment: I have amended the code segment to include the full module.

Comment: Looks like the information you want is inside elements with specific css classes (`pdpEnhanceTitle` and `ManufacturerPartNumber`), so `getElementsByClassName` would likely be useful to look at.

Answer (score 0):

IE is dead and should no longer be used. However, the given offer page can also be accessed with the shortened url https://cpc.farnell.com/SD02808 via xhr (XML HTTP Request). The following code merely shows how the desired information can be read from the loaded HTML code. All safeguards are missing.

The object error in your code shown above occurs because you are trying to set a variable of the data type `String` to `Nothing` like an object variable with `Set strData = Nothing`.

```
Sub GetCPCOfferInfos()

  Dim url As String
  Dim doc As Object
  
  Set doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")
  
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    url = "https://cpc.farnell.com/" & ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .Send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
      
      ActiveSheet.Range("A3") = doc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innertext _
                                & doc.getElementsByTagName("h2")(0).innertext 'Title
      ActiveSheet.Range("B3") = doc.getElementsByClassName("ManufacturerPartNumber")(0).innertext 'Manufacturer Part Number
      ActiveSheet.Range("C3") = doc.getElementById("pdpSection_FAndB").innertext 'Product Overview
      ActiveSheet.Range("D3") = doc.getElementById("pdpSection_pdpProdDetails").innertext 'Product Information
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```